# How to convert object to json in flutter?

Tags: json, object, flutter, dart

I want to convert my object into JSON so I implemented following code

```
import "package:behoove/models/product.dart";

class Order {
  Product _product;
  int _quantity;
  int _id;

  Order(this._product, this._quantity, this._id);

  int get id => _id;

  int get quantity => _quantity;

  Product get product => _product;

  double get orderPrice => _quantity * double.parse(_product.discountedPrice ?? _product.price);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": _product.id.toString(),
        "name": _product.name,
        "price": _product.price,
        "quantity": _quantity.toString(),
        "attributes": {},
        "conditions": []
      };
}
```

JSON from app is

```
{id: 9, name: GoldStar Classic 032, price: 1200, quantity: 1, attributes: {}, conditions: []}}
```

[Screenshot JSON from app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWb5G.png)

But JSON from DartPad is

```
{"id":"1","name":"Sabin","price":200,"quantity":3,"attributes":{},"conditions":[]}
```

[Screenshot JSON from DartPad console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnBTc.png)

How can I get same output on my app. please help. Also why is it not similar on both DartPad and app?

Comment: You can create fromJson method in model class which return factory constructor

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata correct me if I am wrong... fromJson is only to convert json to object right? I need only convert object to JSON.

Comment: Yes you are right I think you need type casting

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata can you please share some code snippet so i could get some hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling `.toJson()` directly use [jsonEncode()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) as in the example (you can run it in DartPad to see difference). Calling `jsonEncode(order)` will give you a properly formatted json.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
final obj = Order();
  print(obj.toJson());
  print(jsonEncode(obj));
}


class Order {
  int id = 0;
  int price = 100;
  String name = 'asdf';
  int quantity = 10;


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id.toString(),
        "name": name,
        "price": price,
        "quantity": quantity.toString(),
        "attributes": {},
        "conditions": []
      };
}
```

Output:

```sh
// simple toJson that ommits quotation marks
{id: 0, name: asdf, price: 100, quantity: 10, attributes: {}, conditions: []}

// properly encoded json
{"id":"0","name":"asdf","price":100,"quantity":"10","attributes":{},"conditions":[]}
```